# WPF send key to textBox

Tags: wpf, keyboard-events

I'm working on a virtual keyboard, but i struggle to send Keys. Nothing happens, except when i hard-add them to the textbox. Here's my code

```
  public static void Send(Key key)
    { //Found online
                var e = new KeyEventArgs(Keyboard.PrimaryDevice, Keyboard.PrimaryDevice.ActiveSource, 0, key)
                {
                    RoutedEvent = Keyboard.KeyDownEvent
                };
                InputManager.Current.ProcessInput(e);
    }


  private void ClickOnKey(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CustomButton cb = sender as CustomButton;
        string text = cb.text;
        Console.WriteLine(text);
        element_to_focus.Focus(); //The textbox
        Send(translate_string_to_key(text));
     }
```

Comment: is there a reason that you don't simply update textbox.text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ProcessInput` seems to only raise the appropriate key-related events, but will not actually modify the text.

If you really want to simulate key presses, you'll need to leverage p/invoke and use  [`SendInput`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput). Luckily, someone's already done the p/invoke work for us and has made their work available:
https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=inputsimulator

It's also available as a NuGet package (I found two versions):
https://www.nuget.org/packages/InputSimulator/
https://www.nuget.org/packages/InputSimulatorPlus/